# Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess problem.

My directory structure look like this:

```
/
HEADER.html
README.html
/stackoverflow/
/stackoverflow/.htaccess
```

.htaccess

```
ServerSignature Off
Options +Indexes
HeaderName /HEADER.html
IndexIgnore HEADER.html
ReadmeName /README.html
IndexIgnore /README.html
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
AddCharset UTF-8 .txt
IndexIgnore *.xml
IndexIgnore *.php
```

My primary directory is /stackoverflow/, when I navigate to this directory via browser I have included HEADER.html and README.html on every site/directories under /stackoverflow/, this works fine.

I added some php code to my HEADER.html (which is in the root directory / ), I am trying to add to htaccess:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm

This not working, I think because the HEADER.html is in the root.

If I try add the AddType... to the /.htaccess (and not to the /stackoverflow/.htaccess) it is overwriting my /stackoverflow/.htaccess rules. Why? How I can add AddType rule to my /stackoverflow/.htaccess to Apache parse html file as php file?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP parser will ignore a file of .html as it is designed to. `.html` should be rendered not processed, if you want to add additional logic to your header file you'll have to convert it to `.phtml` or `.php`. You could also create a new header file which then just includes the html.

About the question regarding the `.htaccess` override that's how apache mod_rewrite works. It's a hierarchal system and will load the first one it comes across starting from / moving towards the requested file.

Answer (score 0):

```
HeaderName /HEADER.php  
AddType text/html .php  
<Files "*.php">  
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php  
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

An .htaccess file affects the directory it resides in and any sub directories. It can't do anything to directories above it in the tree. Check this out the [htaccess docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#how) for more details.

So, if you want to keep the .html extension, you would have to do the "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm" at the root level "/.htaccess". Or, as Matt S suggest change the extension to something that gets processed as PHP.